# Is there an R function that allows you to extract individual lines from a data frame cell that contains multiple lines?

Tags: r, excel

I am importing a csv into R that has columns which contain multiple lines in each cell. I found a function that allowed me to extract each line into its own column in excel using the function =TRIM( MID(SUBSTITUTE( $A2, CHAR(10), REPT( " ",LEN($A2) ) ), (C$1-1)*LEN($A2)+1, LEN($A2)) ) and was wondering if there was a way to perform this same thing in R.

Answer (score 0):

fake data:

```
my_data <- data.frame(
  a = "my
text")

my_data
         a
1 my\ntext
```

In R, line breaks in character strings are coded `\n`, comparable to `char(10)` in Excel.

To separate the "cell" into two rows, we could use `tidyr::separate_rows`:

```
tidyr::separate_rows(my_data, a)
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 2 × 1
  a    
  <chr>
1 my   
2 text
```